# ViewController WILL NOT dismiss

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

```
    WLINewPostViewController *newPostViewController = [[WLINewPostViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WLINewPostViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *newPostNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPostViewController];
    newPostNavigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [tabBarController presentViewController:newPostNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So I just simply push a new UIViewController.
Then after it posts the server callback calls a method with this code from the WLINewPostViewController.m:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                    NSLog(@"Completed");
                }];

                [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

                if (self == self.navigationController.visibleViewController){
                    NSLog(@"self = visibile");
                }

                if (self == self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController){
                    NSLog(@"self = presenting");
                }

            }
```

I tried a bunch of different things and none work. 
I am relatively new to Xcode but after trying

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion]
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
[self.navigationController.visibleViewController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and every other possibility, I am officially stumped. The WLINewPostViewController still won't dismiss.

It Logs out "self = visible"

Comment: what is your purpose? dismiss which viewcontroller from where?

Comment: The question could be clearer on point of which vc is doing the dismissing, but I think there's a reasonable guess available.  Maybe the OP can do a quick edit so that there's no need to guess?

Comment: @vichevstefan dismiss the WLINewPostViewController from inside WLINewPostViewController.m

Comment: Good, this matches my guess, which makes me think the snippet I suggested should work.  The idea is to dismiss the newPostNavigationController which can be accessed from within the WLINewPostViewController with `self.navigationController`

Comment: @danh I tried that. I tried both of these [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; No success

Comment: Hmm.  Thats a bummer.  Please post the context of the dismiss, the whole method that contains it.  Also, can you remove all of that code after the dismiss?  Lets get that dismiss working first and worry later about whatever else you want to happen to the window.

Answer (score 0):

Let me illustrate what you are trying to do

You have a navigation controller with Controller A.
Here you are trying to present another Controller B from Controller A.
Now when you get a callback from the server, you should call dismissViewControllerAnimated from Controller B to dismiss itself.

So after dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: method call, the Controller B will be dismissed and Controller A will be shown automatically. Now you do not need to call popViewControllerAnimated: in completion block again as there is no other Controller in navigation controller to load.

If you have different use case, let me know I can provide solution.

Comment: I called dismissViewControllerAnimated from Controller B and nothing happened. I've added some other relevant edits to the question. thanks for your help

Comment: Try calling [self.navigationController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; to dismiss the presented view controller.

Comment: you can not just dismiss or pop navigation controller, so you can not dismiss or pop WLINewPostViewController as it is root of navigation controller. Only you can do is, once you are done with navigation controller, create a new view controller what ever you want to display and assign it to rootviewcontroller of application.

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting a view over navigationbar instead of pushing it over navigationbar.

When push you pop. When you present you dismiss. So instead of  popViewControllerAnimated you need to use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion

Answer (score 0):

dismiss behaves differently depending on the receiver.  From the docs:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.
>
> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

In short, if the vc on top calls it on itself, it dismisses itself.  Anywhere else on the stack dismisses to that point, animating only the topmost vc.

What's extra confusing (for you and many others) is that the navigation vc has a stack too, and your problem is complicated further by presenting an navigation vc atop a tab-bar vc.

So what to do?  The question is unclear about which vc is the receiver in the posted code (who is `self` in that snippet?).  The text implies that self is a vc on the stack of the presented navigation vc, like...

```
TabBarVC  --- presents ---> NavVC
 |                            | 
 |                            --- viewControllers stack = rootVC, vc1
 |
 ---> viewControllers for each tab
```

... and it's root or vc1 that wants to dismiss.  If I'm right about that, then, given the docs, the solution is clear:

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

will put us back on the tabbar vc on whatever tab was visible when we did the present.

Comment: You helped me understand the situation a lot better. Thanks. Although, it still isn't working.